# How to prepend path to a script's src when using parcel

Tags: reactjs, package.json, parcel

I am using parcel to bundle the files, and for my script tag or link tag containing .tsx and .less files, it will transform those file to the following format:

```
<directory name>-<hash>.<extension>
```

and output .js and .css respectively.

For example, if the original script tag in my index.html is

```
<script type="module" src="index.tsx" defer></script>
```

then when it is on prod, the index.html will have this script tag instead:

```
<script type="module" src="index.a1b2c3.js" defer></script>
```

However, because the files are bundled through parcel, I can't simply prepend the src path in my index.html, such as changing

```
<script type="module" src="index.tsx" defer></script>
```

to

```
<script type="module" src="/path/index.tsx" defer></script>
```

where `path` is something I need to prepend in each script tag's src in order for them to work with the server I am using.

Is there something I can add in my package.json so that it'll automatically prepend `path` to my .js and .css src? Such that the index.html on production will have the following tag:

```
<script type="module" src="/path/index.a1b2c3.js" defer></script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

update build script in **package.json**

`build: parcel build --public-url ./`